# Python scope of variable -referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, django, scope

**Error Produced**

> local variable 'url' referenced before assignment

I have searched for this issue in SO but most of them seem to address the fact that the variable is declared outside the function and needed to be globalized or the variable is being accessed in a member function of a class. This case is different. I don't understand why I am not allowed to call `url` inside the same function.

Looking at the code below, wouldn't `url` be accessible in anywhere inside login function? I believe if this is C/C++ that would be the case. Why is this any different?

**Code**

```
def login(request):
  #  
  #no url declaration here
  #
  if request.POST:
     …
    url = 'main.login.html'
    user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            auth_login(request, user)
            state = 'You are logged in'
            url = 'main.home.html'
        else:
            state = 'You are not logged in due to error'
    else:
        state = 'Incorrect username or password'

    …
 render_to_response(url,{'state':state,'username':username},context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

Traceback points to the last line.

```
render_to_response(url,{'state':state,'username':username},context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

Comment: Neither of these lines is raising that error. The complete stack trace includes the line number. Check it.

Comment: To what line does the error point? Is it the `url = 'main.home.html'` line? Or some line earlier in the function?

Comment: its pointing at ---> render_to_response(url,{'state':state,'username':username},context_instance=RequestContext(request)

Comment: Whittle your code down to the smallest example that still produces the error and post that, because there's no way this could be happening if your ellipses were truly irrelevant.

Comment: It's also possible that he's called `del url` somewhere?  Maybe?  This code example isn't complete enough to explain the error you're getting.

Comment: Can you post your whole code? Are you *positive* that first `url` line is at the initial 4 space block? The usual culprit is mixing spaces/tabs or merely indentation levels within if/else blocks.. if there's an if/else block in your `...` section, check over it with a fine toothed comb.

Comment: I found the problem. The last line in the code example here is indented differently from what it is in the actual code, so you guys didn't see the problem.

Comment: @stackplasm, yeah I knew there was something very important hiding in that `...`. The entire block was indented / url was not something that would always be in the entire context of the function.

Comment: @stackplasm Please don't forget the indentation is always 4 spaces. That is default python code. [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Please go through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you made two change and it will work fine. Define url before checking post method and use return keyword with render_to_response statement.

```
def login(request):
  url = 'main.login.html'
  state = ''
  if request.POST:
    user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            auth_login(request, user)
            state = 'You are logged in'
            url = 'main.home.html'
        else:
            state = 'You are not logged in due to error'
    else:
        state = 'Incorrect username or password'

 return render_to_response(url,{'state':state,'username':username},context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

If you do not define url and state before checking POST method, then it will raise error for GET request.